# Spring Roo + Hibernate: uppercase database name in the query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa-2.0, spring-roo

I've reverse engineered a sample MySQL database with Spring Roo, and I'm trying to insert a record using the Customer entity in this way:

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.setFirstName("Raffaello");
customer.setLastName("Baresi");
customer.persist();
```

However, while the initial connection to the database the insert query fails, so I've enabled the full query log and I've noticed that the schema name is uppercased as ROO_CRM instead of roo_crm.

```
insert into ROO_CRM.CUSTOMER (COMPANY_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) 
values (null, 'Raffaello', 'Baresi')
```

My database.property file contains the lower case name:

```
database.url=jdbc\:mysql\://localhost/roo_crm?zeroDateTimeBehavior\=convertToNull&characterEncoding\=UTF-8
```

While the generated Customer class has an upper case schema attribute of the @RooEntity annotation:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooEntity(versionField = "", table = "CUSTOMER", schema = "ROO_CRM")
@RooDbManaged(automaticallyDelete = true)
public class Customer {
}
```

I thought to lower case the schema name, clean and rebuild for added precaution, but the schema is still upper case in the query. I've also noticed that the Spring-managed Customer_Roo_Entity has the following line:

```
declare @type: Customer: @Table(name = "CUSTOMER", schema = "ROO_CRM");
```

Which is still with the upper case schema, but I'm not allowed to edit that file. What is the correct procedure to solve the problem?

Comment: I don't think the case matters when you refer to a database schema. By the way what database are you using? This could possibly be some other issue.

Comment: Hi @bhagyas, I'm using MySQL on Linux, so for this combination it matters. I just found the solution... I forgot to run the roo shell... I know it sounds kind of stupid mistake, but I'm learning.

Comment: It's okay, cheers and all the best with Roo! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually very trivial solution: it was correct to change the schema attribute of the @RooEntity annotation. What I forgot is that, I should have left the roo shell open and that would have automatically modified the generated Customer_Roo_Entity.aj file.

I started the roo shell and the generated Customer_Roo_Entity.aj was modified and everything worked.